# How to display the Title and Image of virtuemart product when sharing it on Facebook?

Tags: fbml, virtuemart, facebook-sharer

I am building a product catalog website using joomla and virtuemart extension. To let users share my products on facebook, I have added a facebook share button in my product's flypage.

In the flypage I have added the following code:

```
 <div> <a name="fb_share" type="button" ></a> 
 <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
 </script> 
 </div>
```

When I click on the share button it shows only the url of the website. But I want to show the product Title and Image of the product too. I have installed Virtuemart Open Graph plugin but it is not working.

Would you please kindly tell me how to show the title and image of the product when sharing on facebook??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - you have to add `og:tags` to your page where the share/like buttons reside.  The `og:tags` contain things like `og:title`, `og:image`...etc.
You can read more on the usage of the open graph protocol and about the `og:tags` at this URL :
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/